# same line print in c

Tags: c, printf

The follow code below:

```
void day(int d);
void  amountOwed(double i);

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int x = 1;
    day(1);
    double amount = .01;
    amountOwed(amount);
}


void day(int d){
    printf("Day                  Amount Owed                    Total Paid");
    printf("\n---     ------------------------      ------------------------");
}

void amountOwed(double i){
   int a;
   float d;
   for (d = 1; d < 64; d++){
        printf("\n%2f",d);
    }
   for (a = 0; a < 64; a++){
       i *= 2;
       printf("\n  %30.2f", i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

outputs the follow:

```
Day                  Amount Owed                    Total Paid
---     ------------------------      ------------------------
1.000000
2.000000
3.000000
4.000000
5.000000
6.000000
7.000000
8.000000
9.000000
10.000000
11.000000
12.000000
13.000000
14.000000
15.000000
16.000000
17.000000
18.000000
19.000000
20.000000
21.000000
22.000000
23.000000
24.000000
25.000000
26.000000
27.000000
28.000000
29.000000
30.000000
31.000000
32.000000
33.000000
34.000000
35.000000
36.000000
37.000000
38.000000
39.000000
40.000000
41.000000
42.000000
43.000000
44.000000
45.000000
46.000000
47.000000
48.000000
49.000000
50.000000
51.000000
52.000000
53.000000
54.000000
55.000000
56.000000
57.000000
58.000000
59.000000
60.000000
61.000000
62.000000
63.000000
                            0.02
                            0.04
                            0.08
                            0.16
                            0.32
                            0.64
                            1.28
                            2.56
                            5.12
                           10.24
                           20.48
                           40.96
                           81.92
                          163.84
                          327.68
                          655.36
                         1310.72
                         2621.44
                         5242.88
                        10485.76
                        20971.52
                        41943.04
                        83886.08
                       167772.16
                       335544.32
                       671088.64
                      1342177.28
                      2684354.56
                      5368709.12
                     10737418.24
                     21474836.48
                     42949672.96
                     85899345.92
                    171798691.84
                    343597383.68
                    687194767.36
                   1374389534.72
                   2748779069.44
                   5497558138.88
                  10995116277.76
                  21990232555.52
                  43980465111.04
                  87960930222.08
                 175921860444.16
                 351843720888.32
                 703687441776.64
                1407374883553.28
                2814749767106.56
                5629499534213.12
               11258999068426.24
               22517998136852.48
               45035996273704.96
               90071992547409.92
              180143985094819.84
              360287970189639.69
              720575940379279.38
             1441151880758558.75
             2882303761517117.50
             5764607523034235.00
            11529215046068470.00
            23058430092136940.00
            46116860184273880.00
            92233720368547760.00
           184467440737095520.00
```

Is there any way for me to print this statement on the same line?? I am trying to figure out a creative way to do this in c. Also is there anyway for me to format the double underneath day so it doesn't print out as 1.0000 and etc

Comment: Dude, google is a very good friend, for double and printing formating options

Comment: Just be sure that you output everything in the order you want it to be output: before printing anything from day 2, output everything from day 1.

Comment: @hagubear Thanks! I am working on that right now, but how would I go about formatting the doubles underneath the day column to look like an int

Comment: @glglgl Can you be a little bit more clear? I am having trouble understanding your comment. Thanks

Comment: @helpHelpHelp Essentially, I wanted you to direct to the way [gkovacs90 does it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26604160/296974)...

Comment: You should be able to do it in one for loops. I have edited your code [here](http://ideone.com/iSHpEw) check it out. You don't need both for loops.

Comment: @hagubear looks, like exactly what i was aiming for. Thank you!!

Comment: where does this thing about printing the "\n" at the start of the line come from? I see it a lot but I can't understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
for (d = 1; d < 64; d++){
        i *= 2;
        printf("\n%2f  %30.2f",d,i);
    }
```

Maybe it isn't perfect because your for loops don't print the same number of lines, but I think You can fix this little difference.

Comment: looks like exactly what I was trying to attempt!! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstood the question, you simply have to omit the `\n` from the format strings.

Comment: i should've been a little bit more clear, I wanna keep the same format as is, but on the same line next to each other. @Codor